# Merge duplicate values in django query

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a SQL query but I want to know, how can I write in Django format (PostgreSQL). I'm new with django :)

**Suppose, we have data in a table like this.**

```
1: Color: Pink,    Size: 1M 
2: Color: Pink,    Size: 2M
3: Color: Red,     Size: 1M
4: Color: Red,     Size: 3M
5: Color: Yellow,  Size: 2M
```

Expecting output

```
Pink
Red
Yellow
```

> I'm getting output with the below query. But I want to know, how can I query & merge duplicate values in django

```
// id = product_id
colors = Variants.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM  product_variants  WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY color_id',[id])
```

Model:

```
class Variants(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    image_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=0)
```

[Variants model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ZqM.png)

Comment: Can you share the relevant model(s). It is not entirely clear to me how you structured the data.

Comment: I updated my question! @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: please [edit] the question, a comment has no indentation :).

Comment: I updated my question! @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with:

```
Color.objects.filter(variants__product_id=productid).distinct()
```

This will give the `Color` objects for which there is a variant for the given product. The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) call is used to retrieve each color at most once.

Comment: Suppose, we have a single table with colors & sizes as I mentioned in the question. How can we retrieve duplicate values at once? Or can we filter data after querying?

Comment: @SarmadNawab: you can query with `Variants.objects.filter(product_id=productid).values_list('color', flat=True).distinct()`, but that is a bit "ugly".

Comment: `Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id).distinct('color_id')` with this i got my expected output. I got it from your shared reference [.distinct()  Django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: @SarmadNawab: but this will return `Variants` objects. Furthermore this only works for PostgreSQL. It makes not much sense to return `Variants` if you want to use the `Color`, you can query for the `Variant`s for a given `Color`, which is in fact efficient with a `Prefetch` object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#Prefetch